# SSRS Reports fields error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am creating a SSRS report and my output shows a fields which read the respective data for that field AND data from another field. the first 15 rows for the 2columns are ok and the rest have that problem, the first fields for the first column remain blank and the respective data is populated to the other column.

Comment: What is the source of your data?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that if you when into the layout section of the report in SSRS designer and navigated to the Value dropdown, you might have something like this in there for those problematic columns?

=(Fields![col1].Value) & (Fields![col2].Value)